Picovoice Porcupine custom wake word isn't working, file path issue
I trained a custom wake word on the picovoice website and downloaded the ZIP file. Then I extracted it and copied the file path. Here's my code:
import struct
import pyaudio
import pvporcupine
porcupine=None
paud=None
audio_stream=None
try:
    porcupine=pvporcupine.create(access_key="blahblah", keywords=["C:\\Users\\maste\\Downloads\\Jarvis_en_windows_v3_0_0.ppn"])
    paud=pyaudio.PyAudio()
    audio_stream=paud.open(rate=porcupine.sample_rate,channels=1,format=pyaudio.paInt16,input=True,frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length)
    while True:
        keyword=audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
        keyword=struct.unpack_from("h"*porcupine.frame_length,keyword)
        keyword_index=porcupine.process(keyword)
        if keyword_index>=0:
            print("hotword detected")

finally:
    if porcupine is not None:
        porcupine.delete()
    if audio_stream is not None:
        audio_stream.close()
    if paud is not None:
        paud.terminate()

But I get this error:
ValueError: One or more keywords are not available by default. Available default keywords are:\njarvis, hey barista, bumblebee, americano, ok google, terminator, blueberry, hey siri, grasshopper, alexa, porcupine, hey google, computer, pico clock, picovoice, grapefruit

What am I doing wrong? It works fine with a built in wake word. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my formatting of the file path.

I have found the solution. Only cost half of my insanity and a night of no sleep.
When using custom keywords, use keyword_paths= instead of keywords=.
